# IEnumerable<object> from object which is IEnumrable<T>

Tags: c#, ienumerable, boxing

I have a method which takes `(object value)` and convert it to `string` with some tricky rules.

One of those rules is related to when value is `IEnumerable`. In this case i need to process each item in enum:

```
public string Convert(object value)
{
    var valuetype = value.GetType();
    if (valuetype.GetInterface("IList") != null)
    {
        var e = (IEnumerable<object>) value;
        return e.Count() == 0 ? 
            "" : 
            e.Select(o=>Convert(o)).Aggregate("", (c, s) => c+s);
    }
}
```

Of course, if value is `List<string>`, for example, line

`var e = (IEnumerable<object>) value;`

throw an Exception

`` Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object]'. ``

Any ideas, how can I get rid of it?

Comment: do you mean each item in the collection?

Comment: Are you just joining the the string's to together?

Comment: you're using a version of .net that's older than 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

`var e = ((IEnumerable) value).Cast<object>()`

However I think this may fit the bill:

```
    public static string Convert(object value)
    {
        if (value is string) 
            return value.ToString();

        var data = value as IEnumerable;
        if (data == null)
            return string.Empty; // I think you missed this one

        var e = data.Cast<object>();
        return e.Count() == 0 ?
                string.Empty :
                e.Select(o => Convert(o)).Aggregate("", (c, s) => c + s);

    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `valuetype.GetInterface("IEnumerable") != null` for `string` too :)

Comment: Great, `(value as IEnumerable).Cast<object>()` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
var e = ((IEnumerable)value).Cast<object>();
```

Also, `Aggregate` for string concatenation is really costly -- you should use a `StringBuilder` or `string.Concat` or `string.Join` instead. Plus, the `c.Count() == 0` is redundant.

```
return string.Concat((IEnumerable)value).Cast<object>().Select(Convert).ToArray())
```

Comment: problem is value can be `IEnumerable<int>` or `<DateTime>` or whatever

Answer (score 0):

Variance is only supported in generic type parameters in interfaces and delegates with C# 4.0.